# Angular 2: automatic logon using Active Directory user

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular, active-directory

I'm developing an Angular 2 application, and one of the requirements is that the user should log in automatically (without specifying a username and password). The user should be logged on with his Windows user.

Is this possible? I know I can use Windows authentication in my Web API but I suppose there is no way of knowing the user's credentials without him specifying them manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add your site to "Local Intranet" in

```
Chrome > Options > Under the Hood > Change Proxy Settings > Security (tab) > Local Intranet/Sites > Advanced.
```

Add you site URL here and it should work.

Comment: Great! Hit the `UP` button now!